# list comprehension with input().split()

Tags: python, tuples, list-comprehension

I have to read **N** then **N** tuples of two numbers as shown in the example below:

```
3
1 85
2 91
3 73
```

After that I want to sort them based on the second element, with ties broken by the order they came into input. To do that I wanted to save a tuple with 3 elements but I can't figure out how to put that into a list comprehension syntax.

I want a comprehension that would be equivalent to:

```
n = int(input())
l = []
for i in range(n):
    v1, v2 = input().split()
    l.append((int(v1), int(v2), i))
```

Here is what I've tried:

```
n = int(input())
l = [(int(v1), int(v2), i) for v1, v2 in input().split() for i in range(n)]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`tuple()`](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#tuple) and [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
num_tuples = int(input())
lst = [tuple([int(x) for x in input().split()] + [i]) for i in range(num_tuples)]
print(lst)
```

Example input:

```
2
1 2
3 4
```

Output:

```
[(1, 2, 0), (3, 4, 1)]
```

Answer (score 2):

You *could* do something like this:

```
l = [(*map(int, input().split()), i) for i in range(int(input()))]
```

But this is pretty confusing and unreadable, why do something like this when your for-loop is perfectly adequate?

Comment: Just getting used to python's syntax... This `*map` for instance, is pretty new to me... googling to find out more about it right now

Comment: @vmp That's just iterable unpacking inside a tuple literal: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/ So, `(*any_iterable, 2, 3)` etc

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga how were you able to do the above? I get an error on `range(int(input()))` and also on `(*map(...))` saying `SyntaxError: iterable unpacking cannot be used in comprehension`. The python3 version I'm using is `3.6.6`.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga seems in 3.7+ it works, just added an answer too.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start by writing the program out without condensing the syntax to establish our starting point

```
n = int(input())
l = []
for i in range(n):
    v1, v2 = input().split()
    l.append((int(v1), int(v2), i))

l = sorted(l, key=lambda x: (x[1], x[2])) # here is the line I'm adding to sort
print(l)
```

```
$ python3 test.py
3
1 85
2 91
7 91
[(1, 85, 0), (2, 91, 1), (7, 91, 2)]
```

It's a bit complex -- and perhaps worse: very difficult to maintain or read -- to place the two statements in the for loop into a list comprehension (though both of the previous answers show how it can be done), so what I'd suggest here if you want to do a one-liner is to place it in a `map` with a `lambda` function, such as:

```
def my_function(num):
    v1, v2 = input().split()
    return (int(v1), int(v2), num)

n = int(input())
l = map(my_function, range(n))
```

Nice and readable. And if you also want to do the sort (and everything else) in one line, you can of course do:

```
sorted(map(my_function, range(int(input())), key=lambda x: (x[1], x[2]))
# 1 2
# 2 3
# [(1, 2, 0), (2, 3, 1)]
```

Here's what it looks like all together (I'll add a share link once I can figure it out):

[image]

Comment: There's no need for lambda, `map(lambda x: f(x), iterable)` should just be `map(f, iterable)`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga right, thanks for pointing that out: updated.